# @typescript-eslint/naming-convention custom configuration for @emotion style files

Tags: typescript, eslint

Inside a design system I maintain, we use a modified BEM format for the naming of exported @emotion/css JSS styles.

The syntax looks something like this:

```js
Selector_descendant___modifier
```

eg (pseudo code):

```js
// header.styles.ts
export const Header_container___isFlex = css`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
`;
```

Ofcourse, @typescript-eslint/naming-convention doesn't like this syntax. I wonder, is there either a way to create a custom rule to allow for this syntax to be used ONLY inside *.style.ts files? Or failing that, is there some kind of extra custom rule configuration we can add to this eslint plugin, to enforce this syntax?

Comment: Have you already read the documentation for the rule? https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/87cfc6ad3e3312d7b6f98a592fb37e69d5d6880a/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This question can be split into two parts:

1. How to provide two sets of rules for different files?
2. How to custom @typescript-eslint/naming-convention rules to support my custom format?

#### ESLint multiple sets of rules:

From eslint v4.1.0, you can create configuration based on glob patterns, doc: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns

Example from the above link:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"]
  },

  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["bin/*.js", "lib/*.js"],
      "excludedFiles": "*.test.js",
      "rules": {
        "quotes": ["error", "single"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Custom format of @typescript-eslint/naming-convention

You can find the document from @jsejcksn 's comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/87cfc6ad3e3312d7b6f98a592fb37e69d5d6880a/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md

Something like this:

```js
{
  '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': ['error', {
      selector: 'variableLike',
      format: null,
      custom: {
        regex: '^[A-Z]\\w*_\\w+___\\w+$',
        match: true
      }
  }]
}
```

#### Final Solution:

```js
module.exports = {
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': ['error', {
      selector: 'variableLike',
      leadingUnderscore: 'allow',
      trailingUnderscore: 'allow',
      format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase', 'UPPER_CASE']
    }],
  },
  overrides: [{
    files: ['**/*.style.ts'],
    rules: {
      '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': ['error', {
        selector: 'variableLike',
        format: null,
        custom: {
          regex: '^[A-Z]\\w*_\\w+___\\w+$',
          match: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }]
}
```

Change the regex to fit your real case.

Comment: OMG @banyudu, what a solid stack overflow answer. Upvoted and selected as answer! Thank you kindly! :D

Comment: FWIW - i had to tweak the regex a tiny bit
`(^[A-Z]\\w+)|(^[A-Z]\\w+_\\w+$)|(^[A-Z]\\w+___\\w+$)|(^[A-Z]\\w+_\\w+___\\w+$)`